# Securing keys, passwords in a Python application

Tags: python, azure, security, azure-keyvault

My application consists of **Python 3** and **Azure Key Vault**. I want to implement security such that the secrets from Azure Key Vault are not exposed in the application. I also want to protect information that the application requires to connect to Azure Key Vault.

1. How do I protect the data needed to access Azure Key Vault?
2. Once the application has the secrets, how can I protect them in the
   application?

Scenarios I am trying to avoid:

1. A developer to add a `print(my_var)` when debugging and compromising security.
2. A developer accessing the environment variables that would make it possible to duplicate the application and pose as it to access key vault and get secrets.
3. Secrets being logged during runtime, debug and production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about how to protect the Azure AD application data(client ID, client secret) that be used to access Azure Key Vault and if you are using Azure services such as VMs or Azure App services to host your application, you can enable [Azure Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) to access Azure Key Vault. If you do so, you not need to manage Azure application AD data, Azure will manage it on behalf of you, no application info will be leaked.

Once you get your secrets back from Azure KV, you should take care of them yourself in your application by your own way.